# href tag not working in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, outlook-2013

For the life of me I do not understand why my href tags aren't working in outlook 2013. I have other anchor tags that are written the same way in the same html file. 
it seems that the href tags are stripped out altogether. 
They work in all other email clients, except outlook 2013. Is there anything I could be missing? Any help is appreciated.

```html
                                                      <table align="center" class="inner">
<tr>                              

<td align="left" width="65">                               <a href="https://facebook">
<img src="./img/social-fb.png" width="65" style="display:block;">
</a>                               </td>
                              <td align="left" width="65">
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
<img src="./img/social-in.png" width="65" style="display:block;"></a>
</td>
                           </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding target="_blank" on the <a>?

Comment: Like @RasmusBidstrup mentioned, _blank is missing — it's a best practice to add it (many reasons, including if email is opened in browser, _blank will prevent customers from clicking away from opened email). Also, on IMG tag  you're missing border="0" and also at least empty alt="" attribute. Is Facebook link URL is missing "www" part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing:

`<a href="https://www.instagram.com/">`

to:

`<a href="http://www.instagram.com/">`

Outlook may trip over https. A regular 'ol http redirects to https.

Answer (score 1):

Try to always give http at startin of the url 
ex- www.google.com  replace it to https://www.google.